# Simple flash video loop play (played on android) always crash after a few hours

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, video

Why is my flash-based video player on android always crash after a few hours of play?

I'm writing a flash-based Android App. The only thing that native android part do using webview to load a flash swf. The swf acted as the container for all module (which all written in flash as3). One of the module is a simple video module which loop play a set of video playlist forever.

I've considered memory leak, but after printing memory usage (using flash's System.totalMemory), the result is always around 12MB to 14MB (which seems normal for two videos). I've test the flash using both webview and other third party swf player for android (such as "Swf Player" and "Smart SWF Player"), all results in crash after a few hours.

The as3 code is simple and I can't see any possible cause for this. Here is my main class:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.media.Video;
import flash.net.NetConnection;
import flash.net.NetStream; 
import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;

public class simpleVid extends MovieClip {      
    private var video:Video;
    private var nc:NetConnection;
    private var ns:NetStream;
    private var uri:Array = new Array("vid1.flv", "vid2.flv");
    private var counter:int = 0;

    public function simpleVid() {
        // constructor code
        nc = new NetConnection();
        nc.connect(null);
        ns = new NetStream(nc);
        video = new Video();
        video.attachNetStream(ns);

        ns.client = {onMetaData:videoReady, NetStatusEvent:onStatusEvent};
        ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onStatusEvent);

        ns.play(uri[counter]);
        stage.addChild(video);

        counter++;
        counter = counter % 2;
    }

    public function videoReady(item:Object){
        video.width = 1280;
        video.height = 720;
    }

    public function onStatusEvent(event:NetStatusEvent):void{
        if (event.info.code == "NetStream.Play.Stop") {
            ns.play(uri[counter]);
            counter++;
            counter = counter % 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there is anything I missed or I did wrong in this code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: first write the question properly ,it mean nothing. it is unclear

Comment: Hi, I've try to emphasis my question in the front. Hope it can clarify my problem.

Comment: Why not publish the swf to a native APK? I assume it has to do with the Native Webview loading the SWF, and the error occurs somewhere there, instead of inside the swf.

Comment: `System.totalMemory` has never seemed accurate to me, likely because it does not include the actual runtime memory. If you can, get Adobe Scout and use that to profile memory and CPU usage to see if either gradually builds over time. Also remember that depending on Android device, you may not have much memory to play with and I believe there are arbitrary limits set on what an app can use in some (if not all) versions of Android)

Comment: That ", NetStatusEvent:onStatusEvent};" part seems awkward to me. But it surly isn't the problem. Your code seems totaly ok.
Why not make an AIR Android app ? Since your native app is only loading a swf ...

Comment: @JoshJanusch: Thank you for your suggestion, I've extracted some data. I notice a memory usage jump at the moment of crashing. Before the jump, the total memory is 8M; mostly used for bitmap and actionscript object. Then it jump to 4G (yes, it's 4,202M, crazy I know); most of them (4,194M) used by Network Buffers. Since my video is in the SDCard, I'm wondering if it is Scout's bug? Other than that, I don't see any abnormalities. Or can you suggest another data to look at?

Comment: @djib: That's because I was working with CS5 which don't have "air for android" setting. I've managed to get CS5.5 now and ran flash debugger. The result is: No error catched by the debugger, while my video is crashed. From the log (YAY! I can write log to the device now I'm using AIR!) I noticed that some event is not triggered. Sometimes it's video.stop, sometimes video.ready. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem "mysteriously" disappeared after I switch to AIR instead of flash.
No code is changed, I only changed the release setting from Flash player to air for android.
Now it can run continuously for several days without problem.